# Get first 3 integer

Tags: ruby

I have a couple of 5 digit integers. how can i get the first 3 digits of the integers
like
927, 795, 973, 562 and 969

and get the last integer

like

4, 2, 1, 5, 6

example:

```
92774
79512
97331
56295
96926
```

Comment: Can you show us your code so far and where you're stuck? This would help us to help you.

Comment: Can the first digit(s) be zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in rails console
something like

```
=> 92774.to_s.first(3).to_i
=> 927
```

in irb

```
 => 92774.to_s.chars.first(3).join.to_i
 => 927
```

Comment: String does not have a method called `first`.

Comment: omg i use rails console to test this case

Comment: Well, still a nice method if you use Rails!

Comment: @hirolau yeah I'm confused

Comment: `92774.to_s.chars.first(3)` returns `["9", "2", "7"]`

Comment: @Stefan thx, i edited own answer

Answer (score 6):

If they're integers then just divide by 100 (integer division truncates the answer – rounds it towards zero)

```
92774 / 100 # => 927
```

To get the last digit, use the mod (`%`) operator which gives you the remainder after division

```
92774 % 10 # => 4
```

Answer (score 5):

```
92774.to_s[0..2].to_i  # 927

92774.to_s[-1].to_i    # 4
```